# How to dynamically find web element by XPath in Selenium using Katalon

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, keyword, katalon

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'"+ ProjectName +"')]")).click();`

> I tried to use this code to find web element dynamically, but when I tried to call it on my test case seems that it cannot have an input value since this code is a part of my custom keyword code. Can someone help me try to find a way on how to do it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on element you can use following method:

```
public void clickOnElement(String xpath) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
}
```

To format a String according to passed parameter you can use this:

```
public String stringFormat(String template, String parameter){
    return String.format(template,parameter);
}
```

For the specific use like in your question the `template` can be defined like this:

```
String elementTextTmplt = "//*[contains(text(),'%s')]"
```